# I am trying to create custom modal bottom sheet with line on the top, how can I achieve that?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, bottom-sheet

I tried to change the style, but apart from the round corners nothing worked.Here example of bottom sheet https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O92g.jpg.
Can anyone helps? Here what I tried and I got shadow line after I opened modal  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHNA.jpg
I am trying to create custom modal bottom sheet with line on the top, how can I achieve that?
**MainAct**

```kotlin
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var btnShowBottomSheet: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnShowBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.idBtnShowBottomSheet);
        btnShowBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog, null)
            val btnClose = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.idBtnDismiss)
            btnClose.setOnClickListener {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            dialog.setContentView(view)
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

**Bottom_sheet_xml**

```kotlin
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_corners"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_rectangle"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                >
                <!--image view for displaying course image-->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/idIVCourse"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        
                <!--text view for displaying course name-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idTVCourseName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:text="DSA Self Paced Course"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <!--text view for displaying course tracks-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idTVCourseTracks"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:text="Course Tracks : 30"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
                <!--text view for displaying course duration-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idTVCourseDuration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseTracks"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:text="Course Duration : 4 Months"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
        
                <!--button for dismissing our dialog-->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/idBtnDismiss"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/idIVCourse"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Dismiss dialog"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what did you try ? what error are you getting ? what are you aiming for ? we need more details !

Comment: when i asked what you tried, i meant "share the code of whatever you tried"

Comment: @ADITYARANADE check plz

Answer (score 0):

Based on the xml and code you have posted you have to make the below changes:

1.Change the xml `android:background` structure to be like below. The drawable which has rounded corners must be set to the 2nd child of RelativeLayout instead of parent and all other RelativeLayouts must have android:background="@android:color/transparent":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_corners">
        <!--image view for displaying course image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <!--text view for displaying course name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="DSA Self Paced Course"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--text view for displaying course tracks-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseTracks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="Course Tracks : 30"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <!--text view for displaying course duration-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTVCourseDuration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idTVCourseTracks"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:text="Course Duration : 4 Months"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <!--button for dismissing our dialog-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/idBtnDismiss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/idIVCourse"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Dismiss dialog"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

where `@drawable/rounded_top_corners` will be:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

2.You have to set a custom theme style for BottomSheetDialog with a Transparent window dialog like below:

```
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.MyBottomSheetDialog)
```

where `R.style.MyBottomSheetDialog` is your custom BottomSheetDialog style defined in styles.xml like below:

```
<style name="MyBottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

After the above changes you will have a Transparent Window BottomSheetDialog with a line on top like:

[image: bottom_sheet_dialog]